# Have the void loop() fuinction in Arduino terminate

Tags: loops, arduino, void

I am building a countdown timer with Arduino. After it hits zero I would like it to stop looping. I do not want to use the setup() so it runs only once. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: add a test a the beginning of your loop function and return if timer is done. Have you planned to add a switch to restart the countdown ?

Comment: `while(true){}` when you want to do nothing anymore... or use a switch to restart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void loop(){
    //...
    if(timer){
        // Your code
    }
    else{
        // Code to restart timer or to do when timer hits 0
    }
}
```